# Does AWS offer Websites or only Virtual Servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Azure has the concept of websites which offer the user no OS maintenance. I only seem to see Virtual Machines available on AWS? What am I missing?

I am interested in deploying nodejs express apps, but don't want to manage vm's. In azure the equivalent in an azure website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Presently, I don't think there's a convenient, out-of-the-box nodejs deployment on AWS.  You will have to setup and manage that VM.</s>

Correction (Update):
AWS does have a nodejs deploy via Elastic Beanstalk.

Edit: 
After looking over joynet's [really nice wiki on node-hosting](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/node-hosting) they list [awsbox](https://github.com/mozilla/awsbox) - which looks to make it easier, but you'll still have to do some work starting up the VM and accessing it.

Comment: Note - Since your question refered to NodeJS, I'd recommend changing the question Title to include that piece. To "Does AWS offer Websites or only Virtual Servers?" - answer is yes, via s3 you can host a static site (e.g. plain js, html, css, image based) see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html